# How to prevent creating duplicates of edges between the same vertices in OrientDB?

Tags: java, sql, graph, orientdb

I have vertex "Person" and edge "Knows". Here is SQL example of how I created it.

```
CREATE CLASS Person EXTENDS V;
CREATE PROPERTY Person.name STRING;

CREATE CLASS Knows EXTENDS E;

INSERT INTO Person (name) VALUES("John")
INSERT INTO Person (name) VALUES("Ann")
INSERT INTO Person (name) VALUES("Harry")
```

When I create an edge between John knows -> Ann
by

```
CREATE EDGE Knows FROM (SELECT FROM Person WHERE name = "John") 
TO (SELECT FROM PERSON WHERE name = "Ann")
```

it creates it and every thing is ok.

[image]

But problem occurs when I accidentially create edge several times.

[image]

For the relationship "Knows" duplicates are redundant, but for some other ones like "Visited" (John [Visited ->] New York) duplication of edges are desired feature if edge "Visited" has property "date".

I tried to solve it by adding unique index to edge "Knows", but after that I am able to create edge between only one pair of vertices.

And checking every time edge for existence before creation doesn't seem to me a good idea as well.

How to solve this in correct way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The straight forward solution is to create an index on EdgeClass[out, in]. To do this, you also have to define the schema for the edge class:

```
CREATE CLASS Knows EXTENDS E
CREATE PROPERTY Knows.out LINK Person
CREATE PROPERTY Knows.`in` LINK Person
CREATE INDEX Knows.out_in ON Knows (out, in) UNIQUE
```

Comment: Throwing `com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexException: Index with name 'Knows.out_in' cannot be created on class 'Knows' because the field 'in' is absent in class definition` on CREATE INDEX Knows.out_in ON Knows (out, in) UNIQUE`

Comment: I am using 2.2.31 version of OrientDB on Windows 10

Comment: Try to add back-tick when creating "in" property, that should be the problem. I just updated the original answer

Comment: Little update here: in v 3.0.1 we added CREATE EDGE UPSERT that skips duplicates. The unique index is still needed though

Comment: I have created UNIQUE index as you said and it works fine. When I execute query `create edge EFriend UPSERT from #81:24 to #81:0` several times in OrientDb Studio it works as expected (one edge is created). But when I try to execute the same in from PHP (protocol v. 36), i get `... found duplicated key 'OCompositeKey{keys=[#81:24, #81:0]}' in index ...` exception. Why is it so?